# Need help to solve this subquery in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need your help to solve this query:

```
select idiomas.bandeira,conteudos.nid, dreg, titulo, tag from conteudos 
            inner join conteudos_tag on conteudos.nid = conteudos_tag.cod_conteudo
            inner join tagstree on conteudos_tag.cod_tag = tagstree.nid
            inner join idiomas on conteudos.nid_idioma = idiomas.nid
            order by conteudos.nid desc limit 5
```

And this return:

```
img/idiomas/pt.png;30;2013-04-04 12:41:00;titulo;Voip
img/idiomas/pt.png;30;2013-04-04 12:41:00;titulo;Linux
img/idiomas/pt.png;28;2012-08-07 01:50:18;Números e Tarifários;Números e tarifários
img/idiomas/pt.png;27;2012-08-07 01:33:48;Terminais VoIP2;Terminais
img/idiomas/pt.png;26;2012-08-03 19:06:13;Rede Estruturada;Rede Estruturada
```

And i need that return this:

```
img/idiomas/pt.png;30;2013-04-04 12:41:00;titulo;Voip, Linux
img/idiomas/pt.png;28;2012-08-07 01:50:18;Números e Tarifários;Números e tarifários
img/idiomas/pt.png;27;2012-08-07 01:33:48;Terminais VoIP2;Terminais
img/idiomas/pt.png;26;2012-08-03 19:06:13;Rede Estruturada;Rede Estruturada
```

The change is at line 1

Tks
Rui

Answer (score 2):

Well it's a bit hard to say since I don't really know which column is which, but I'd estimate:

```
select idiomas.bandeira,conteudos.nid, dreg, titulo,
GROUP_CONCAT(tag, SEPARATOR ', ') AS tag from conteudos 
        inner join conteudos_tag on conteudos.nid = conteudos_tag.cod_conteudo
        inner join tagstree on conteudos_tag.cod_tag = tagstree.nid
        inner join idiomas on conteudos.nid_idioma = idiomas.nid
GROUP BY conteudos.nid
        order by conteudos.nid desc limit 5
```

This will group all of the results by the seemingly unique `nid`.  If there are multiple tags for the same `nid`, they will be stored in one column and separated by `,`.  It may be more accurate to group on *all* non-aggregate columns, or also use `GROUP_CONCAT` if there are other non-unique columns.

Comment: seems right to me, i was gonna put the same thing but you beat me to it